# SQL Using TOP n with UNION, but only want results of second query if first does not have enough records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a sql statement that works something like a store. I have two queries and I want n records from the first query, but if there is less than n, I want the rest from the second.

I tried using TOP n and UNION

```
SELECT TOP 20 FROM (
     (SELECT * FROM t1)
UNION
     (SELECT * FROM t2))
```

but the results are from both tables regardless of how many are in t1. Basically, I want the first query to have precedence. If 5 records exist there and I want them and I want the rest from t2.

Comment: sivilian, Do it multi-step. Select from table t1 with all the criteria for t1 and then do an EXCEPT with table t2 store results in a temporary table. Lastly UNION the 2 datasets. I am not sure which database it is. But SQL Server has EXCEPT and INTERSECT. Also tag the appropriate database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column that identifies the query, so the first one have precedence.

```
SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM ((SELECT 1 as query, * FROM t1)
       UNION
      (SELECT 2 as query, * FROM t2))
ORDER BY query
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a CTE to place a sort order on the two tables and then use that in an order by clause

```
declare @foo1 table(
    bar INT
)
insert into @foo1
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
--,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)

declare @foo2 table(
bar INT
)
insert into @foo2
values (101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(109),(110),(111),(112),(113),(114),(115),(116),(117),(118),(119),(120)


;with base_data as (
select 
0 as sort,
f1.bar
FROM @foo1 f1
UNION
SELECT
1 as sort,
f2.bar
FROM @foo2 f2
)
select top 20 bar
from base_data
order by sort, bar
```